# How do get the edges along the path returned by dijkstra in orientdb

Tags: dijkstra, orientdb, shortest-path

currently the algorithm returns only the vertices , but how to get the edges that it chose ? as there can be multiple edges between the vertices

Answer (score 0):

I'll have to modify current function. Search source code 'OSQLFunctionDijkstra.java' for existing function and inside 'getDistance' method it should be easy to print 'Edge' information.